# Unable to get response when code 401,422 Unauthorized in retrofit in android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have onResponse and onFailure block when requesting for api. In response block checking response.isSuccessful() when success mean code 200 then i can easily parse the response but when 400,401,422 then i can't able to parse response.when i am trying to get body or errorBody then return `null.

```
if (response.isSuccessful())
{
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String json = gson.toJson(response.body());
   Log.e("isSuccessful",json);
}
 else {
    Log.e("errorBody",response.errorBody().toString());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(response.body());
    Log.e("errorBody",json);
 }
```

Comment: What does your server/API return as error message?

Comment: when i print message, its return 401 Unauthorized

Comment: No, I mean is there any JSON data that you are expecting in body or errorBody?

Comment: in postman {
  "email": [
    "The email has already been taken."
  ],
  "phone_number": [
    "The phone number has already been taken."
  ]
}